# box-shadow animation in safari not fading

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations, box-shadow

I have this animation working in Chrome and Android, while in Safari and iOS rings are not fading away but staying black. What is causing that?

Is there way not to use box-shadow and achieve same effect?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVZWQa

```html
<div class="loader">
  <span class="ring ring-1"></span>
  <span class="ring ring-2"></span>
  <span class="ring ring-3"></span>
  <span class="ring ring-4"></span>
</div>
```

```css
@yellow: #FFD200;
@brown: darken(@yellow, 45%);

body {
  background: fade(@yellow, 90%);
}

.loader {
    position: relative;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    .ring {
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        animation: pulse 8s ease-out infinite;
        &.ring-2 {
            animation-delay: 2000ms
        }
        &.ring-3 {
            animation-delay: 4000ms
        }
        &.ring-4 {
            animation-delay: 6000ms
        }
    }
    @keyframes pulse {
        0% {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px @brown;
            transform: scale(0);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        25% {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 45px rgba(darken(@yellow, 40%), 0.66);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        50% {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 25px rgba(darken(@yellow, 30%) 0.33);
        }
        100% {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(darken(@yellow, 20%) 0);
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the compiled CSS, you are passing a hex colour value to `rgba()`. eg `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(#997e00 0);`. This is probably the issue.

Comment: Updating the colour values to valid rgba values fixes it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOJqap. I'm not sure if there is a way to make `darken()` return a rgb colour.

Comment: You are right.. I missed commas =[

Answer (score 0):

as @Turnip pointed out I had missing commas.